# Can I use elementary's workspace switcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: workspaces

Is there a workspace switcher for Compiz like elementary's? It's faster and nicer than Ubuntu's current one. Alternatively, is it possible to use elementary's window manager instead of Compiz?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer one of your questions

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gala
  gala --repĺace
```

That will install gala the elementary window manager.

Comment: Please don't do this on any production machine. Elementary is still in early development and so is gala. Please be aware that it might be difficult to reverse any changes you made.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a workspace switcher for Compiz like elementary's?

Typically workspace switchers are integrated in window manager. So, I don't believe you can use separate workspace switcher in compiz. I don't know of any workspace switcher independent of window manager

> is it possible to use elementary's window manager instead of Compiz?

**No**. Elementary uses `gala` window manager. But if you try to use it, it will kill compiz (which in turn will kill Unity) because two window managers can't run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems trying to install in Ubuntu 14.04

There was an error with `libmutter0d` that was solved by running

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo apt-get update
```

Now the right version of `libmutter0d` is installed

Comment: could you please give the full steps for installation? That's what the question asks for