# How to install Gala on Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, window-manager, elementary-theme

I tried to install Gala window manager (the windows manager of Elementary OS) on Xubuntu 14.04 as described for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199343/can-i-use-elementarys-workspace-switcher-in-ubuntu/199362#199362),
but seems like there is an unmet dependency. The error is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gala : Depends: libmutter0d  3.12.2-1ubuntu99~elementary0.3.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also installed the `libmutter0d` package but the error persists. Is there something I can do to get through this?

Since the beta1 of the new version of Elementary (based on ubuntu 14.04) is testable, another option would be installing the beta version of gala. I'm not sure if it is possible, but is yes, what are the necessary step to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: No solutions found there. Gala seems to be installable in Ubuntu versions 13.10 downward only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo apt-get update
```

then the right version of libmutter0d is there

Comment: In this way Gala can be installed, but if I launch it two errors appear and it crashes: "libGL error: failed to authenticate magic 1" and "libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo" . I don't know if they are related to the virtualbox session only, or the package doesn't work properly.

Comment: @user47224 I suspect that problem is not related to the original difficulty installing it. You might want to post a separate question to ask about that.