# Xubuntu workspaces overview like elementary OS

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces, elementary, workspace-switcher

I have moved from elementary OS to Xubuntu, because it's faster and with less animations, but there is one thing that I miss a lot - the workspace overview.

Is there a way to accomplish something similar in Xubuntu?

[image]

Comment: similar question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/199343/can-i-use-elementarys-workspace-switcher-in-ubuntu

Comment: Kinda, but the answer is more than 3 years old when eOS was in heavy development

Comment: Does "a way to accomplish something similar" also include a way *without* installing Gala window manager? Any other requirements i.e. the suggested way should trigger the workspaces overview by keyboard shortcut and/or hover by mouse cursor etc.?

Comment: I am not saying that I want to stick with the default window manager, but if there is a simpler way I'd prefer it. I haven't change WM on any distro before and as uncovered land it sound scary. I'd appreciate any guidance.